# How to prevent users from using ALSA directly?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I setup pulseaudio in system mode and it currently works fine. However, I noticed that users have access to ALSA directly, e.g. this works:

```
ogg123 -d alsa song.ogg
```

[ArchWiki mentions this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#User_privileges):

> Usually, local users have permission to play audio and change mixer levels.
>
> To allow remote users to use ALSA, you need to add those users to the `audio` group.

However, the user isn't a member of `audio`.

Is there any way to limit access to ALSA to the `pulse` user alone (user running the system mode pulseaudio daemon)?

Comment: What permissions have you set in `/dev/snd/`?

Comment: Everything is owned by root:audio, pemission 660.

Comment: If you are running Pulseaudio: Are you *sure* this user is accessing ALSA directly, and not connecting to Pulseaudio? (Check e.g. with `pavucontrol`).

Comment: Interestingly, it seems `ogg123 -d alsa song.ogg` doesn't actually work when Pulseaudio is not running - I get `ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1713:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card` so you're definitely right. However, I don't quite understand how this works, i.e. how is it using pulse through ALSA?